# Expressing a convex Polytope as a sublevel set of a function

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Given an n-dimensional polytope $P$ in $\mathbb R^n$, Given as a convex hull of a finite set of points, $S$ I would like to construct an expliict formula for a function $f\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $P=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n \Big|\ f(x) \le 1\right\}$
Is there any nice known closed formula? It seems that there should be one in existance, as everything is piecewise linear.

Moreover, I would like to ask the same question in the case P is given as intersections of half planes (hence, the data I have are normal vectors to the plane and distance from the origin)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If it's given as the intersection of half-spaces $\{x \mid v_i \cdot x \le d_i\}$, then you can take $f(x) = \max_i ( v_i \cdot x - d_i)$ and have
$P = \{x \mid f(x) \le 0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the Minkowski-Weyl Theorem (see, e.g., [Zieglers Book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xd25TXSSUcgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The proof of the "main theorem" *essentially* gives an algorithm to do that.